# Emacs: multiple views of same file

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to view the same file in 2 buffers, one at normal scale and the other zoomed out, to see the whole buffer (as in notepad++ document map: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/assets/images/docMap.png ).

Is there any way visit the same file in different buffers, so that each buffer can have different settings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x clone-indirect-buffer</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x clone-indirect-buffer-other-window</kbd> aka <kbd>C-x 4 c</kbd>), and then you can set the font in one of the buffers real small.

You can make the font smaller or larger in a buffer with the bindings <kbd>C-x C--</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-+</kbd>, which run the command `text-scale-adjust`.

There was a mode that someone made that did this splitting/shrinking automatically, but I'm unable to find it.

Comment: But how to use different font for the same face in the two buffers?

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I want. Thanks very much!

Comment: @MiserableVariable you can use `text-scale-adjust` and similar functions to set font sizes in the two buffers

Comment: Note that `C-x 4 c` is a convenient standard binding for `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window`

Answer (score 9):

You want to install the `minimap` package (it's in GNU ELPA) which does just that.